How to increment specific array element indexes in a TypeORM column using `.set` or dynamic raw SQL?
I'm working on a NestJS project with TypeORM, and I have a UserStats entity that contains an array column (e.g., globalReads). I need to increment specific indexes in this array column dynamically based on a condition.
Here’s my current attempt:
async incrementIndexesByOne(
  columnName: string,
  indexes: number[],
  where: FindOptionsWhere<UserStats>,
  options: { queryRunner?: QueryRunner; } = {},
): Promise<void> {
  if (!indexes.length) {
    throw new Error('No indexes provided. The indexes must not be empty.');
  }

  // Dynamically construct the SET clause
  const setClauses = indexes
    .map((i) => `"${columnName}"[${i}] = "${columnName}"[${i}] + 1`)
    .join(', ');

  const [query, parameters] = this.repository
    .createQueryBuilder('us', options.queryRunner)
    .update(UserStats)
    .set({ [columnName]: () => setClauses }) // workaround to attempt a raw SQL string
    .where(where)
    .getQueryAndParameters();

  await options.queryRunner.query(
    query.replace(`"${columnName}" =`, ''), // hacky replacement to remove TypeORM's invalid clause
    parameters
  );
}

The Issues:

TypeORM’s .set does not support passing raw SQL strings directly as parameters, which is why I’m using the workaround query.replace() to modify the query. This feels hacky and error-prone.
I cannot find a clean way to increment specific array indexes in a column while still using TypeORM’s query builder and avoiding plain SQL queries.

What I’ve Tried:

Passing raw strings in .set using functions like () => "my_column"[1] = "my_column"[1] + 1, but TypeORM does not handle this correctly.
Using queryRunner.query to execute raw SQL, although it works, I’d like to keep the query builder if possible for maintainability and consistency.

My Goal:
To dynamically construct and execute an SQL query to increment specific indexes of an array column (globalReads) while preserving the benefits of TypeORM’s query builder (e.g., parameterization).
For example:
UPDATE "user_stats"
SET "globalReads"[1] = "globalReads"[1] + 1, "globalReads"[2] = "globalReads"[2] + 1
WHERE "userId" = '123';

Question:
Is there a clean way to achieve this functionality in TypeORM using the query builder, or is raw SQL (via queryRunner.query) the only option? Are there any alternatives or best practices for handling such cases?
Any guidance would be much appreciated!
